# Python Path and imports

Tags: python, windows, kubernetes, path, python-import

I've been encountering persistent import errors with a project I'm working on and would greatly appreciate any assistance. The project is hosted on GitHub: [amir-without-models](https://github.com/Keped/amir-without-models)

The issue arises when I clone and run the code locally; I'm faced with numerous import-related errors. Despite trying various solutions, I haven't found a fix yet. Intriguingly, the same code runs smoothly on our Kubernetes pods, suggesting that the code itself is correct.

A typical example of the problem is with the import statement:

```
from client.utils import query_fields
```

This line fails to compile locally, yet it functions perfectly within our Kubernetes environment.

Altering the import path to:

```
from client.client.utils import query_fields
```

resolves the local issue and allows unit tests to pass, but this change disrupts the functionality on Kubernetes.

In summary, I need to find a way to make the imports work without altering them, maintaining compatibility with both the local environment and the Kubernetes setup.

I am currently working on a Windows operating system and using PyCharm as my IDE.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or has insights on how to resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The main question is from where are you triggering your project.

Comment: from the top directory

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  You say it works locally, but not on Kubernetes; do you have the same problems in a simpler environment, like a non-cluster Docker container?  What is in your image's Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see github project "amir-without-models" you shared

So, maybe I'm not 100% sure

You cannot run on locally because of import errors, but work on K8s Pods?

Maybe you can try below

**1.ENV PYTHONPATH on Dockerfile like below**

example of Dockerfile

```
FROM [your image name]
...
...
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:[project path]/client:[project path]/client/client"
```

**2.or at yamls**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: your-deployment-name
  ...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: your-container-name
        image: your-image-name
        env:
        - name: PYTHONPATH
          value: "[project path]/client:[project path]/client/client"
```

**3.To do same thing at local?**

you said your OS is Window and using PyCharm

use 'set' on your cmd (powershell... etc)

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\..\your_project\client;C:\Users\..\your_project\client\client
```

and then restart your IDE and try to run it